# Suggest some better real time, event driven file replication software for WIndows than fileReplicationPro?

Tags: replication, database-replication, data-synchronization

We are currently using `FileReplicationPro` for real time replication. Please suggest some better real time, event driven file replication software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Vice Versa](http://www.tgrmn.com/web/file_replication.htm)** 
You can configure ViceVersa to run real-time, scheduled or on-demand.
ViceVersa will pull or push the most current data from the source to the destination.You can download its free trial [from here](http://www.tgrmn.com/web/download.htm) 
**[SyncBack4all - File sync Realtime](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/syncback4all-file-sync-realtime.htm)**
SyncBack4all is an easy to use file backup and file synchronisation application.
It automatically analyses, synchronises, and backs up your emails, photos, contacts, music, documents, and other important files locally - between desktops, laptops, servers, external drives, and Windows Mobile devices, as well as remotely through FTP and SFTP.Automatically Sync or Back Up to Multiple DevicesAutomatically synchronise and back up your important files between desktops, laptops, servers, and external drives over local network or the Internet.SyncBack4all file sync software uses a unique synchronisation algorithm, combined with an intuitive interface to meet your synchronisation and backup needs effectively.SyncBack4all file synchronisation software combines reliability with an extremely easy to use interface to compare, synchronises, and backup your emails, contacts, photos, music, and other important files. 
**[AllSync](http://www.file-sync-software.allsync.info/backup-software/file_replication.htm)** 
AllSync will pull or push the most current data from the source to the destination.
You can schedule jobs to run nightly, weekly, or at any time needed. Only files that have changed will be copied, making replication very fast and efficient.
If you need to replicate files between computers, laptops, desktops, workstations, servers, or to any type of external storage, AllSync will provide you with solid reliable file replication
**[IReplicator](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/ipreplicator.htm)** 
IPReplicator(R) for Windows provides scalable, secure and automated, real-time and scheduled, file replication over LANs, WANs and the Internet. It does all this while controlling and minimizing network bandwidth usage and replicating over TCP/IP connections, even from behind firewalls.It works as a powerful distributed replication system, made up of Replicator agents installed on each Windows server, which is administered from a central Console application. 
**[SureSink](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/suresync.htm)** 
 SureSync is a cost-effective data management solution that provides you with flexible and reliable file synchronization and replication. Whether you need to synchronize files between PC's or multiple servers, SureSync will help you get the task done.SureSync delivers a reliable solution to organizations and individual users as it uses byte by byte comparisons to ensure replication tasks are efficient and maintain data integrity.Continuous, real-time replication and synchronization is one of the many features that ensure high data availability and enhanced performance with SureSync's SPIAgent option.